# Prototypal Inheritance Representation in Developer Console When Using `Object.create`

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance

I have a simple piece of JavaScript code creating object `b` using `Object.create` and passing object `a` as the argument:

```js
const a = {};
const b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b);
```

It is my understanding that `Object.create` will point the `__proto__` of `b` to `a` when creating this new object.

And I can confirm my assumption by logging some values:

```js
console.log(b.__proto__ === a); // true
console.log(a.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.__proto__ === null); // true
```

But the result of logging `b` in the developer console is somewhat confusing as the value of `b.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` doesn't seem to be `null`:

[image]

Comment: There are no standards governing how objects should appear when logged to the console. It is up to each implementation to do what they want. The WHATWG published [a Living Standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) of what `console.log` should do in terms of format strings and the like, but still leaves it to implementations to determine how to show object. If you want to talk about a specific implementation, tag the question with that browser. But know you're making assumptions about the internal representations of JavaScript internals based on essentially one group's decisions.

Comment: Expanding a getter property like `__proto__` in a prototype object actually invokes the getter on the logged value, i.e. it's getting `b.__proto__`, which displays `a` again. Your understanding of the prototype chain is fine. Do not click on `__proto__`, rather scroll down to see the *[[prototype]]* being `null` on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand your point. But I get the same result in both Firefox and Chrome, therefore I assume I'm misunderstanding something about the prototypal inheritance.